# How can I get system configuration (like user/token) for Artifactory in jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins-plugins, artifactory

The [artifactory jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin) is used inside jenkins, and I configured the user/token inside the system configuration, like [image: user config for artifactory pro]

How can I get those information for script inside job shell ? so I can use to publish artifacts over REST API. (artifacts jenkins plugin can't provide my needs).

Will be nice if it can expose the system environment like `$ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME`.

Also I notice the information is saved in `$JENKINS_HOME/org.jfrog.hudson.ArtifactoryBuilder.xml`, if it is `config.xml`, I may possible to access via JENKINS API, is this approach possible ?

```
http://your.jenkins.url/computer/(master)/config.xml
```

Comment: Just a comment on "artifacts jenkins plugin can't provide my needs" - did you look at the generic deployment? It's rather flexible.

Comment: No, my needs is control the copy items with own logic, here I just want to reuse the user/name